# how to navigate to a Page in content place holder on hyperlink click

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Master Page

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;" runat="server">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <!-- Navigation -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-left: 0px">
                        <div class="container" style="height: 70px; width: 1300px; text-align: left">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                    <img src="Styles/Images/Orion_logo1.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Orion" />
                                </a><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ORION</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="float:none;display:table-cell;width:1%;text-align:center;height:70px;vertical-align:middle">
                                    <li class="active" style="text-align:center;margin: auto;vertical-align:middle"> 
                                        <%--<a href="testMasterChild.aspx" id="YourLink" runat="server" target="_Blank" data-toggle="tab" style="text-align:center;height:70px;width:110px;">Default View</a>--%>
                                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkHome" data-toggle="tab" style="text-align:center;height:70px;width
                                            :110px;" NavigateUrl="~/testMasterChildPage2.aspx">Default View</asp:HyperLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="testMasterChild.aspx" data-toggle="tab" style="text-align:center;height:70px;width:110px"  > One View</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="testMasterChildPage2.aspx" runat="server"  target="_Blank" data-toggle="tab" style="text-align:center;height:70px;width:110px" >Admin View</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="margin-top:70px">
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="cphMain" runat="server" >

    </asp:contentplaceholder>
    </div>
</body>
```

Child Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mstOrion.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testMasterChildPage2.aspx.cs" Inherits="CLMWidgets.testMasterChildPage2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
    <h1> testing ChildPage 2!!</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Above I have added Master Page and Child page code.
i have one master page and one child page i have to open a child page in content place holder after clicking on hyperlink please help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. MasterPage is not a page per se, it is a template. So when you are opening some page in the browser, it is always some content page. Now, are you trying to navigate from one page to the other via hyperlink in the menu?

Comment: i know master page is a template.
I have two hyperlinks of different webforms that i have to open in a content place holder of master page

Comment: Did you try loading usercontrol dynamically into a container on button click?

Comment: I have simple requiremtn i have 3 Web forms
1.Default.aspx
2.Home.aspx
3.about.aspx
On hyperlink click of each link it should open in a content place holder of master page
in startup default page will open later user can click any hyperlink